Why is Psukei Dezimra in Yom Tov the same as Shabbat?
Why is Psukei Dezimra in Yom Tov the same as Shabbat? Why isn't there a difference in the Psalms (Nusach Sfard, Ashkenazi)? Some of the additional Psalms, in comparison to Yom Chol, include connections to Shabbat, while others relate to the creation of the world, which are both unrelated to Yom Tov.

Fwiw, historically, there were some communities who had some differences.
